# How to merge PDFs into a PDF Portfolio?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am looking for the functionality that creates PDF Portfolios:

[image: Multiple PDFs packaged into one]

The image shows the free adobe reader that can be downloaded from Adobe (duh!). When I open this particular PDF, I was surprised that it has all these Layout, Files and Attachment features. It is definitely not the normal "PDF merge". It is more like a package with multiple PDFs.

Can itextsharp do this? What is the search term for this PDF functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [PDF Portfolios](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/overview-pdf-portfolios.html). You can create PDFs like this with iTextSharp. Here are a couple of C# examples from the [iText book](http://itextpdf.com/book/):

- [Chapter16 - KubrickCollection](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter16&ex=KubrickCollection)
- [Chapter16 - KubrickMovies](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter16&ex=KubrickMovies)

If you choose to download the KubrickMovies result file, change the extension to ".pdf". Just noticed it now - will try and fix the error this weekend.

Comment: To save everyone from the trouble of stepping through the code, the relevant steps for generating a portfolio includes (1) Create a PdfCollection with schema (2) create a PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded() with parameter fileDisplay containing a filename with extension of the embedded file type otherwise the included file will appear as unknown filetype (3) create an add a PdfCollectionItem to PdfFileSpecification to get an entry in the portfolio pane (2) use PdfWriter.AddFileAttachment to attach the FileEmbedded.

Comment: As usual the Adobe link has rotted away. :-(

Comment: @MartinSchröder - thanks for the heads up. :) Link fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To generate pdf portfolio (using iTextSharp) first we need to create a collection, then store it.
Example read one pdf file, create from it a collection of 2 files hello.pdf,united_states.pdf finally store as Test.pdf

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Document pdfDoc = null;
        FileStream fstr = null;
        try
        {
            pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            fstr = new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create);

            var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fstr);
         
            pdfDoc.Open();

            pdfDoc.Add(new Chunk());
            PdfCollection collection = new PdfCollection(PdfCollection.TILE);
            var filePath = @"somePDF.pdf";

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            var pdfDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
            pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.Moddate, new PdfDate(fileInfo.LastWriteTime));
           
            pdfWriter.Collection = collection;
            PdfFileSpecification fileSpec = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(
                pdfWriter,
                filePath,
                fileInfo.Name,
                null
            );
            pdfWriter.AddFileAttachment("united_states.pdf", fileSpec);
            fileSpec = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(pdfWriter, filePath, fileInfo.Name, null);
            pdfWriter.AddFileAttachment("hello.pdf", fileSpec);

            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            pdfDoc.Close();
            pdfDoc = null;
            fstr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple sample to show how we can attach files to a new PDF file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace PDFAttachment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            {
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));               
                pdfDoc.Open();

                pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("Test"));

                var filePath = @"C:\path\logo.png";
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                var pdfDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
                pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate(fileInfo.LastWriteTime));
                var fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(pdfWriter, filePath, fileInfo.Name, null, true, null, pdfDictionary);
                pdfWriter.AddFileAttachment("desc.", fs);
            }

            Process.Start("Test.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Or to an existing PDF file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace PDFAttachment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var reader = new PdfReader("Test.pdf");
            using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream("newTest.pdf", FileMode.Create)))
            {
                var filePath = @"C:\path\logo.png";
                addAttachment(stamper, filePath, "desc.");
                stamper.Close();
            }

            Process.Start("newTest.pdf");
        }

        private static void addAttachment(PdfStamper stamper, string filePath, string description)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            var pdfDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
            pdfDictionary.Put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate(fileInfo.LastWriteTime));
            var pdfWriter = stamper.Writer;
            var fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(pdfWriter, filePath, fileInfo.Name, null, true, null, pdfDictionary);
            stamper.AddFileAttachment(description, fs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this only adds the file as attachment (at the side bar in my OP image), but not under "Files" in the toolbar as I have cricled in Red. I need it to be under the "Files" section.

Comment: This is a "PDF Portfolio". For more info read the section "16.2.4 PDF packages, portable collections, or portfolios" of "iText in action, 2nd edtion" book.