# Dictionaries and Schemas in iTextSharp Collections

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am attempting to use the iTextSharp library (version 4.1.6) to generate an Acrobat Portfolio file that contains all files located within a specified Windows 7 directory. When I run the code below, it throws an exception that states "The document has no pages" at

```
document.Close();
```

Despite reviewing the sample iTextSharp code at these sites

[Kubrick Collection Example](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter16&ex=KubrickCollection)

[Kubrick Movies Example](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter16&ex=KubrickMovies)

[How to insert files into folders of an existing PDF portfolio with folders using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027074/how-to-insert-files-into-folders-of-an-existing-pdf-portfolio-with-folders-using)

and looking over the iTextSharp object model here

[iTextSharp documentation](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/5ef5e099-b5b8-4ddf-4f17-5b3ed869b4ed.htm)

I am not grasping how to associate my iTextSharp dictionary with my collection (PDF Portfolio) file. In fact, I do not fully understand how the schema and dictionary for an iTextSharp portfolio/collection affect the final generated collection or each other.

I would very much appreciate help making the code below work, but I would also greatly appreciate any explanation that could illuminate the functional relationship between dictionaries, schemas, and collections within iTextSharp.

**EDIT**

Per mkl's comment I added

```
document.Add(new Paragraph("Added Text"));
```

to the code below, which resolved the exception and generated the portfolio file. However, the information from the dictionary statements

```
PortfolioDictionary.Put(PdfName.CREATIONDATE, new PdfDate(DateTime.Now));
PortfolioDictionary.Put(PdfName.ID, new PdfNumber(i));
```

and the setting for the initial document

```
collection.InitialDocument = "itextDoc.pdf";
```

are not being added to the portfolio/collection. As alluded to in the original question, I suspect some code is needed to insert the dictionary information into the collection and that the schema code I am using may also conflict with the dictionary information in some way. Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.collection;


namespace iTextSharpTest
{
class CreatePortfolio
{
    const string portfolioPath = @"C:\ExportedFiles\TestPortfolio.pdf";
    const string portfolioFile = "TestPortfolio.pdf";
    const string SourcePath = @"C:\ExportedFiles";
    static private readonly string[] keys = new[] {
    "Type",
    "File"
};

    static void Main()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(portfolioPath, FileMode.Create);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Added Text"));
        PdfCollection collection = new PdfCollection(PdfCollection.DETAILS);
        PdfCollectionSchema schema = CollectionSchema();
        collection.Schema = schema;
        collection.InitialDocument = "itextDoc.pdf";
        writer.Collection = collection;
        PdfCollectionItem collectionitem = new PdfCollectionItem(schema);
        PdfTargetDictionary PortfolioDictionary = new PdfTargetDictionary(true);

        string fileName;
        string destFile;
        int i;
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath);
        PdfFileSpecification fs = null;

        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
            i = 1;

            if (fileName != portfolioFile)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(SourcePath, fileName);
                fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, filePath, fileName, null);
                collectionitem.AddItem("Type", "pdf");
                fs.AddCollectionItem(collectionitem);
                fs.AddDescription(GetDescription(i, fileName), false);
                PortfolioDictionary.Put(PdfName.CREATIONDATE, new PdfDate(DateTime.Now));
                PortfolioDictionary.Put(PdfName.ID, new PdfNumber(i));
                i = 1 + 1;
                writer.AddFileAttachment(fs);
            }
        }
        writer.AddFileAttachment(fs);
        document.Close();
        stream.Close();
        //writer.Close(); //commented out while temporarily throwing exception
    }

    private static string GetDescription(int id, string fileName)
    {
        return string.Format("<{0}>{1}", id, fileName);
    }

    private static PdfCollectionSchema CollectionSchema()
    {
        PdfCollectionSchema schema = new PdfCollectionSchema();
        PdfCollectionField type = new PdfCollectionField("File type", PdfCollectionField.TEXT);
        type.Order = 0;
        schema.AddField("Type", type);
        PdfCollectionField filename = new PdfCollectionField("File", PdfCollectionField.FILENAME);
        filename.Order = 1;
        schema.AddField("File", filename);
        return schema;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Also add some content to the document, some tiny paragraph.

Comment: @mkl Thank you! It would never have occurred to me that adding text to the document would resolve the exception, yet the added text would never appear in the final Acrobat Portfolio. This was a huge help. Now to figure out the correct way to insert dictionary information into the collection (per my edit above). Again, much appreciated.

Comment: @mkl, I just noticed that text added via `document.Add` as discussed in the previous comments DOES get added to the generated Acrobat portfolio. It is added to the portfolio cover page. For my application this is mitigated by adding a single space -- `document.Add(new Paragraph(" "));` -- and then having the portfolio open to a contained document (thus hiding the blank cover page), but thought this worth mentioning for future readers.