# C# itextsharp - Create PDF, Create Folder within Folder, Place PDF in deepest Folder

Tags: c#, datagridview, directory, itext, pdf-generation

I am a complete beginner in C# and I was looking for some help regarding this project I have to make.

I am using Windows Forms and itextsharp alongside Microsoft Access. My objective is to make the program, after the user interacted with the DataGridView and filed some information on text boxes, create a PDF file (with the DataGridView on it) and then create a Folder (with name being a Machine ID given by the user before) within a Folder (with name being Client ID given by the user before) to allocate the PDF in.

This code only formats the DataGridView slightly and saves the PDF (by asking the user where).

```
    public void exportgridtopdf(DataGridView dgw, string filename)

    {
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        PdfPTable pdftable = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1, 4, 1, 1, 1 });
        pdftable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
        pdftable.WidthPercentage = 100;
        pdftable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        pdftable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

        iTextSharp.text.Font text = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        //add header
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgw.Columns)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText, text));
            cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
            pdftable.AddCell(cell);
        }

        //add datarow
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgw.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), text));
            }
        }

        var savefiledialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
        savefiledialoge.FileName = filename;
        savefiledialoge.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
        if (savefiledialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(savefiledialoge.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document pdfdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, stream);
                pdfdoc.Open();
                pdfdoc.Add(pdftable);
                pdfdoc.Close();
                stream.Close();


            }


        }
    }
```

The most similar case that I found was here: [How to insert files into folders of an existing PDF portfolio with folders using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027074/how-to-insert-files-into-folders-of-an-existing-pdf-portfolio-with-folders-using)
I tried implementing (what I thought I could use) but I couldn't get any reference for it or any actual progress towards my goal.

```
    public class FolderWriter
    {
        private const string Folder = @"C:\Path\to\your\pdf\files";
        private const string File1 = @"Pdf File 1.pdf";
        private readonly string file1Path = Path.Combine(Folder, File1);
        private readonly string[] keys = new[] {
    "Type",
    "File"
       };
    }
```

I am sorry for my lack of knowledge and for possibly little information given. I can try to upload more code if you need something specific.

Thanks in advance,

Filipe Almeida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the sourcecode below.

For some explanation.
First I'm creating a couple of variables like `folder1`, `folder2InsideFolder2` and `fileName`.
The resulting structure is goint to look like this: `folder1\folder2\pdffile.pdf`

You can basically set my variables to the inputs you already got, like Machine ID, Client ID etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            string folder1 = "DocumentName"; // AKA Machine ID
            string folder2InsideFolder1 = "SomeID"; // AKA Client ID
            string fileName = "FancyPDFDocument2000.pdf";

            // The next line is building a of the two outside folders where the .pdf file will be placed in
            string directoryName = Path.Combine(folder1, folder2InsideFolder1);
            // directoryName is now: DocumentName\SomeID\

            // Let's try to create the directory
            try
            {
                // This line creates the directory using the path that was just created
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // Risen when directory couldn't be created see documentation of Directory.CreateDirectory
            }
            
            // now create the final path consisting of both directories and the .pdf file name
            string finalFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName);
            // finalFilePath is now: DocumentName\SomeID\FancyPDFDocument2000.pdf

            // From here on you can use your remaining code to generate the .pdf file you can use the variable finalFilePath for that
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input!
I tried implementing your code but couldn't really pull it off, at what moment are the folders and file created in your code? I can't seem to find them.
This is supposed to happen after the user clicks a "Save" Button but how can I connect this code that you give me to that button?
Thanks once again,

Comment: I just updated my solution with a bit more explanation and I added a couple more comments to my example. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm afraid this is a misunderstanding... the op wants to create a portfolio pdf in which there are folders to arrange attachments. This is not about folders in the file system.

Comment: Ah, ok, maybe you're right. It's hard to understand what op actually needs

Comment: Yes, I am trully sorry for my bad explanation but english isn't my mother tongue and to add to that my programming knowledge is very low
What i pretend my program to do without user input (besides clicking on the save button on my interface) is to create a pdf and place it in a folder within a folder (that the program also creates when pressing save)

Comment: That's what my code can do, it creates a folder within a folder, and creates the path for the pdf file. That path is in finalFilePath. The folder is created by Directory.CreatDirectory(directoryName)

Comment: Ok, I will try as soon as I can to implement it.
One question how do I associate this code with a button? How do I "say" to the program that when that specific button is pressed it's time to "create the file and folders and save them to X place"

Comment: When you use Winforms, there is a Click event for every button. If you're in the Winforms designer just double click a button and a new method is created for you that is executed when the button is clicked.

Comment: Finally managed to implement your code, thank you for your time explaining everything! It's working wonders

Comment: That's great to hear! Keep it up, and one day you will be able to code almost anything ;)