# Is there a way to create pdf packages/portfolios in abcpdf9?

Tags: abcpdf, abcpdf9

I am looking to create pdf packages/portfolios using abcpdf9. What is the way to do it? 
I have just started exploring abcpdf9. Any sample codes/link??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with abcPDF.

One way to approach it is to use iTextSharp.  The following article shows some information on how to approach it.

[How to merge PDFs into a PDF Portfolio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833572/how-to-merge-pdfs-into-a-pdf-portfolio)